# Adding a row and copying the information from the original row for every day in a date range in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, range

I have a Google Sheet where information from a Google Form is dumped.  Two of the columns create a date range and I would like for the sheet to automatically create a new row of information for every date of the range and copy all the other information from the original row for every row that is created.  In the end, every date in the range has it's own row regardless of it being 2 days or 25 and all the the information gathered through the form be present for each day

[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkScp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will do the trick for you.  My spreadsheet is below after running.  I just append it to the bottom of the starting data.

```
function convertDateRangetoRows()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var rngB=[];
  var day=86400000;
  rngB.push(rngA[0]);
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    rngB.push(rngA[i]);  
    if(rngA[i][0] && rngA[i][1] && rngA[i][0]!=rngA[i][1])
    {
      var dt0=new Date(rngA[i][0]);
      var dt1=new Date(rngA[i][1]);
      var days=(dt1.valueOf()-dt0.valueOf())/day;
      var dt=dt0.valueOf();
      for(j=0;j<days;j++)
      {
        dt+=day;
        rngB.push([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dt), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy"),'',rngA[i][2],rngA[i][3],rngA[i][4]]);
      }
    }
   var intermediate='nothing'; 
  }
  var rngb=sht.getRange(sht.getLastRow()+1,1,rngB.length,rngB[0].length);
  rngb.setValues(rngB);
 var end='the end is near';
}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I thought if I gave a sample sheet I could adapt the formula/function/script to fit my need but I'm still doing something wrong.  In my actual sheet the "Date of Trip" is column C and the "Return Date" is Column G.  Another issue I found is that when new data comes in from the form it automatically overwrites whatever is the next row it's using.  Is there a way to add the rows that are triggered by the date range to the bottom of the spreadsheet, beginning on row 2000.  I have another sheet that is sorting all the data.  Thanks Again

Comment: I'll need to see the data along with an explanation of what you want next.  You might just try moving on to another question.  Please check this one off as done and I'll help you with the next example.

Comment: I did make another post with basically the same title and linked a copy of the sheet.  Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: I can't find it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396220/adding-a-row-and-copying-the-information-from-the-original-row-for-every-day-in