# Adding a row and copying the information from the original row for every day in a date range in Google Sheets #2

Tags: date, google-sheets, range

I have a Google Sheet where information from a Google Form is dumped. Two of the columns create a date range (columns C and G) and I would like for the sheet to automatically create a new row of information for every date of the range and copy all the other information from the original row for every row that is created. In the end, every date in the range has it's own row regardless of it being 2 days or 25 and all the the information gathered through the form be present for each day.  If there is not a date in column G, it is only a one day trip and there is no need for additional rows. To make things more difficult when someone submits a form, the information is entered into the row directly beneath the last one that it filled, so these new rows filled by the date range will need to be down the sheet, possibly beginning at row 2000 or more as this sheet will have a lot of information in a few months.  As you may see in the sample, there is another sheet in the workbook that performs all the sorting.  Thanks for any help.

[Sample Document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1skT7OVQ5FKGr8SaRkPBMmqTCnRtfl48O3VbK1EvrNwM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think that it's better to leave the sheet that's linked to the form alone.  Don't do anything with it.  It's a good place to keep your submissions.  When you get a form submission then use onFormSubmit trigger to append the new rows to another sheet.  I called mine ResponseReview.  Then you can do anything you want with that because all of the new data will just be appended to the bottom.  What do you think?  Do you want to do that?

Comment: I'm up for whatever you think is the easiest fix.  Just let me know what to do and I'll be out of your hair.  The shared file is a copy, so you are welcome to do whatever you think is best to it and I'll follow your lead on the original.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a form submit event and attach the following code to it. Also you'll need to create a sheet name 'ResponseReview'.

```
function formSubmitEvent1(e) 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadsheetID');
    var sht=ss.getSheetByName('ResponseReview');
    sht.appendRow(e.values);
}
```

The above code will need the SpreadsheetId in the openById Method. This code will append any new rows to the end of the ResponseReview sheet.

The code below will expand any entrees that have a date in column 3 and 7 and it will also remove the end date in column 7 from that first row.  I use the fact that if column 3 is not empty and column 7 is not and column 7 is no equal to column 3 then that's a row that needs to be expanded.  So I have to remove the end date so that it won't continue to get expanded when it's run again in the future.  We could figure something else out if you need to keep than end date. We could add a don't expand column at the end.

```
function convertRangetoRows()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('ResponseReview');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var rngB=[];
  var day=86400000;
  rngB.push(rngA[0]);
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    rngB.push(rngA[i]);  
    if(rngA[i][2] && rngA[i][6] && rngA[i][2]!=rngA[i][6])
    {
      var row=rngA[i].slice();//returns a new copy of the array by value
      rngA[i][6]='';//deletes the end date by reference so it also deletes the one thats already been pushed into rngB
      var dt0=new Date(row[2]);
      var dt1=new Date(row[6]);
      var days=(dt1.valueOf()-dt0.valueOf())/day;
      var dt=dt0.valueOf();
      for(j=0;j<days;j++)
      {
        dt+=day;
        row[2]=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dt), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");//original array unchanged
        row[6]='';//original array unchanged
        rngB.push(row.slice());//push in a copy
      }
    }
   var intermediate='nothing'; 
  }
  var outrng=sht.getRange(1,1,rngB.length,rngB[0].length);
  outrng.setValues(rngB);
  var end='the end is near';
}
```

This is what my spreadsheet looks like before running the expansion function:

[image]

And After:

[image]

And now you can leave the sheet linked to the form alone and let it be an archive for submitted data.

Comment: @Saket Thanks for the info about passing arrays by value using the slice().

Comment: I hate feeling this dumb!  Trying to follow your directions and am getting an error: 'TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 5, file "Code")'.  Here is the link to the actual spreadsheet.  Please work your magic and then I'll unshare and try to learn...  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pq_jlzMMvKY99HGc9iFrxjXshkZc2lb4Vde0YsFQc-c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You cant run this function`function formSubmitEvent1(e) 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Pq_jlzMMvKY99HGc9iFrxjXshkZc2lb4Vde0YsFQc-c');
    var sht=ss.getSheetByName('ResponseReview');
    sht.appendRow(e.values);
}` directly. You have to hook it up to an onFormSubmit  trigger.  Without the trigger their is no event and so event.values is undefined.  The e parameter represents the event object.

Comment: Run the onOpen() to authorize it and get a mytools menu.  Then run the convertRangeToRows function to authorize it and it should do it's magic on ResponseReviews.  I just copy the current data into that sheet for now.

Comment: Also I should mention that when you hook up to the on form submit trigger, set the notification to immediate at first and then you'll get quicker messages in case there is a problem.  If all is well, then go back and set notifications to one of the other choices.  It helps to save server bandwidth and we all have to do our little part to make everything work better for everyone else.

Comment: Outstanding!  One more issue.  Can the script change the date of trip so that every date in the range will have it's own date?  For instance right now, if the range is 2/1/2018 - 2/4/2018, the dates are 2/1/2018, 2/4/2018, 2/4/2018, 2/4/2018 and it will sort much better if they were 2/1/2018, 2/2/2018, 2/3/2018, 2/4/2018.  I re-shared the file.  Thanks  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pq_jlzMMvKY99HGc9iFrxjXshkZc2lb4Vde0YsFQc-c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's so close to being perfect!  The formulas that I used to calculate mileage and Fuel are not making the trip to the 'ResponseReview' sheet.  Only the information from the form is transferring.  Also, if I use the 'ResponseReview' as the sheet that I copy and sort on the 'sort' sheet, will all the triggers and the data be pulled automatically so that it is always current?  Right now, 'formSubmitEvent1' is triggered On form Submit while 'onOpen' and 'convertRangetoRows' are triggered On change.  Correct?  Thanks again

Comment: I would trigger onOpen and convertRangeToRows on an onOpen trigger because none of that is valuable unless your looking at it. And then I'd still have convertRangeToRows in the menu.  Also keep in mind that OnChange only responds to a user initiated change not an appendrow.

Comment: The cell formulas at not available to the formSubmit event.  So you'll probably have to add them yourself like you presumably did on the form linked sheet. I try to minimize my dependence upon triggers.  They're asynchronous and by their very nature problematic.

Comment: I would build the mileage and fuel calculations into a script and avoid the use of cell formulas altogether.

Comment: That's a great idea but considering that 72 hours ago I knew nothing of scripts and now I feel I know even less....I'm a little lost to say the least.  My plan is to have the sheet you have been kind enough to work on receive, calculate mileage and fuel, and sort. Then pick and copy the columns needed on the spreadsheet below.  Basically, once up and running, I will very seldom open the spreadsheet that you've been working so I would like everything to automatically happen and then the copied column along with one troublesome vehicle column will be shared for everyone to view.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X4ZiOsDDOvRS6K5xNInPwgzttwBIxhS_HVixt0sQrSQ/edit?usp=sharing